# JavaScript code is not compatible on edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a small JavaScript code, it works on chrome but It's not being compatible on edge. what can i change to make it compatible?

```
     var radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')

    for (let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
        radioBtns[i].addEventListener('input', function () {
            document.querySelector('#estimate').innerHTML = `Total Due = $${this.value}`
        })
    }
```

Comment: "not compatible"?  What happens when you run this in edge?  What errors are you getting?  What does it actually do?

Comment: refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266572/i-want-to-display-price-every-time-user-checks-the-radio-boxes

Comment: The prices are not being displayed on edge

Comment: Have you stepped through it in the debugger? Is `$${this.value}` being properly evaluated? What is that? I'd add the three semicolons you're missing to eliminate that issue as a possibility.

Comment: @isherwood That's string interpolation (template literals) preceded by a `$` sign.  The interpolation syntax is `${....}` inside backticks.

Comment: @jamesbond That is what it is *not* doing.  **What is it *actually* doing?**  Is it displaying "Total Due = " with nothing following it?  Or is it displaying nothing at all?  Is it even entering your event handler? Is your for loop actually looping over the controls?

Comment: I know what the code is. What's the value? Where does it come from?

Comment: What version of Edge are you talking about? What errors do you get? **Errors** are the most important thing here. "Not working" is completely useless as a diagnostic. We need more detail and specifics.

Comment: It appears that the version of Edge you are using may be interpreting the leading `$` as an escape sequence character - which it then doesn't recognize because they are unsupported. As others have recommended, simple change `$${this.value}` to `$ ${this.value}` and see what the result is.

Answer (score 0):

Change `input` into `click`, then the code will work in Edge.

```js
var radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]')

for (let i = 0; i < radioBtns.length; i++) {
    radioBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.querySelector('#estimate').innerHTML = `Total Due = $${this.value}`
    })
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="100" /><text>100</text>
<input type="radio" name="quantity" value="200" /><text>200</text>
<div id='estimate'></div>
```